# Property 'append' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, openapi-generator

i am generating code with the openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript-nestjs from an openapi yaml file.

The gerenator generated the following code:

```
  let queryParameters = {};
    if (ids) {
        ids.forEach((element) => {
            queryParameters.append('ids', <any>element);
        })
    }
```

It´s generated from this definition

```
- name: ids
    in: query
    required: false
    schema:
      type: array
      items:
        type: integer
        format: int64
```

But when I try to compile it with tsc I will get this error:

```
Property 'append' does not exist on type '{}'.ts (2339)
```

Comment: *"The gerenator generated the following code"* That's fairly shocking, given that blank objects don't have an `append` method. I would have expected that to start with `let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();` (or `FormData`)

Comment: Yes, so the question is, why is the generator generating a blank object

Comment: Sounds like a bug.